# Get windows preventing sleep in swift macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sleep

I'm developing a Swift application for macOS and I would like to retrieve the list of windows that are preventing Sleep. Like the column in Activity Monitor->Energy.
Is there a way to retrieve this attribute in Swift?
Thank you

Comment: IDK why this was closed. It's totally focused.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
you can do this with:

```
var assertions: Unmanaged<CFDictionary>?
if IOPMCopyAssertionsByProcess(&assertions) != kIOReturnSuccess {
   fatalError("Error with assertions")
}
```

and in there you can find various assertions, and also Prevent screen dim and system stop